# How do you group data by percentile in Tableau, ignoring nulls

Tags: tableau-api, percentile

I am trying to bin my data based on Age in Tableau. There is a skewed distribution in my age column and I would like to group my data based on percentages. Here is the code that I have:

```
IF [Age]<={FIXED :PERCENTILE([Age],.2)} THEN "<20th" 
ELSEIF [Age]<={FIXED :PERCENTILE([Age],.4)} THEN ">20-40th"
ELSEIF [Age]<={FIXED :PERCENTILE([Age],.6)} THEN ">40-60th" 
ELSEIF [Age]<={FIXED :PERCENTILE([Age],.8)} THEN ">60-80th" 
ELSEIF [Age]<={FIXED :PERCENTILE([Age],1)} THEN ">80th" END
```

I was looking at the counts of my dataset and it looks like the count distribution is equal. This is how it looks like:

[image: Age distribution count]

It looks like I am getting an equal distribution of ages because I have null elements. How can I remove all the null values when I am generating this graph and have an equal number of counts for the 5 bins?

Comment: I'm guessing here that you have null values because there a null ages. Will filtering out null ages solve it?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried filtering Age_Bin

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the bar for your "Null" age bin and hit "exclude" that should remove that bar from your graph by filtering out whatever data qualifies for that bin, assuming that is the intended result.

If that isn't the intended result, then you likely have null values for the Age column in your datasource. To confirm, right-click on the Null bar and hit "View Data" and click the second tab. Should should show a more detailed view of what the data from the source actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Place Age_Bin on the filters shelf and uncheck "Null"